# Measuring reverse transcription yield?

Tags: reverse-transcription

Is there any measurement I could perform after RT that allows me to check the efficiency that the procedure had? Nanodrop cannot be used as remnants of RNA and poly T primers mask measure, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nanodrop may be fine for the volumes but as you rightly guessed it is not so easy to distinguish DNA from RNA (and primers). [Qubit](http://wetlab.izzid.com/2008/Feb/Review_of_Qubit/) (invitrogen) is a sensitive, dye based quantification assay. You can use that for estimating cDNA yield. The kit contains different dyes for DNA, RNA and protein estimation.

Answer (score 0):

Treat with RNAse and spec at 260.

A spec can definitely be used. The extinction coefficient (Beers Lamberts Law) will not  be calculating measuring  NTPs, just intact dsDNA.